# Why is my bind mount visible outside its mount namespace?

Tags: linux, namespace, bind-mount

So I'm trying to get a handle on how Linux's mount namespace works.  So, I did a little experiment and opened up two terminals and ran the following:

**Terminal 1**

```
root@goliath:~# mkdir a b
root@goliath:~# touch a/foo.txt
root@goliath:~# unshare --mount -- /bin/bash
root@goliath:~# mount --bind a b
root@goliath:~# ls b
foo.txt
```

**Terminal 2**

```
root@goliath:~# ls b
foo.txt
```

How come the mount is visible in Terminal 2? Since it is not part of the mount namespace I expected the directory to appear empty here.  I also tried passing `-o shared=no` and using `--make-private` options with `mount`, but I got the same result.

What am I missing and how can I make it actually private?

Comment: mounts are system-wide, not specific to a shell environment.  shared, slave, private, and unbindable are not what you think they are.  read `man mount`.

Comment: @cas: Agree that `--make-private` is not what I want.  But, isn't that the point of mount namespaces (that they're not system wide)?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you are on a systemd-based distribution with a `util-linux` version less than 2.27, you will see this unintuitive behavior. This is because `CLONE_NEWNS` propogates flags such as `shared` depending on a setting in the kernel. This setting is normally `private`, but systemd changes this to `shared`. As of `util-linux` 2.27, a [patch was made](https://github.com/karelzak/util-linux/commit/f0f22e9c6f109f8c1234caa3173368ef43b023eb) that changes the default behaviour of the `unshare` command to use `private` as the default propagation behaviour as to be more intuitive.

**Solution**

If you are on a systemd system with `util-linux` prior to version 2.27, you must remount the root filesystem **after** running the `unshare` command:

```
# unshare --mount -- /bin/bash
# mount --make-private -o remount /
```

If you are on a systemd system with `util-linux` version 2.27 or later, it should work as expected in the example you gave in your question, verbatim, without the need to remount. If not, pass `--propagation private` to the `unshare` command to force the propagation of the mount namespace to be private.

Answer (score 0):

this not worked in ubuntu, (15.04 and 14.04). it worked on fedora.
and for fedora. whether you need --make-private or not, you can also check

> cat /proc/self/mountinfo | grep shared

if shared, it means some other namespace still can see that mounts. Then it is systemd related issue. You can use --make-private to make it work

Answer (score 0):

On Debian 9 with `util-linux` prior to 2.27, [Dave's solution](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/246468/377345) does not work for me. However, this works:

```
mount --make-rprivate -o remount /
```

Note that there's a prefix `r`, which means *recursively*.